# Merging two tables without duplicating

Tags: mysql, sql, qsqlquery, sql-merge

I need to merge two user tables to one without duplicates.

for example : in my database i have tables en_user and kn_user and there are few users exists in both so i when i run an query to merge kn_user with en_user then unique users present in kn_user should be copied to en_user where users present in both should not be merged.

for better understanding my tables are

en_users table

```
**id    name** 
1     Rakesh
2     Deepu
3     sudha
4     sandeep
5     Anil
```

kn_user table

```
**id    name** 
1     Ashwini
2     Rakesh
3     sudha
4     sunil
5     Anil
```

so when in merge kn_users with en_users in need this output

en_users table

```
**id    name** 
1     Rakesh
2     Deepu
3     sudha
4     sandeep
5     Anil
6     Ashwini
7     Sunil
```

Comment: I think u should make unique key of combination of  entities which are unique here you only given "name" as unique so make is unique key
for new table. Then fetch old tables all data and insert into new table by using "INSERT INTO IGNORE".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a query that does what you want:

```
select (@rn := @rn + 1) as id, name
from ((select id, name, 1 as priority
       from en_users
      ) union all
      (select id, name, 2
       from kn_users k
       where not exists (select 1 from en_users e where e.name = k.name)
      )
     ) ek cross join
     (select @rn := 0) params
order by priority, id;
```

The logic in the subquery is to take everything from one table and then only non-matching rows from the second table.  The example is based on `name`.

The query is careful to assign the final `id` based on the example in the question -- first assigning ids from the "en" table then the "kn" table, and in order by ids in the two tables.

Comment: Sorry i am new to sql, please let me know @rn?

Comment: What is meant by @rn ? in our query

Answer (score 0):

```
Set @ID = 0
Select @ID:=@ID+1 AS ID,t1.Name 
from (Select name from en_users
union
Select name from kn_users) as t1
ORDER BY t1.Name
```

The ID's will be different. But you are changing the ID's anyway.